# Skyrim Special Edition Character's voices not working

Tags: sound, wine, pulseaudio, games, lutris

So I am a total noob when it comes to Linux. I finally made the switch from Windows yesterday to the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and I'm really happy with it aside from the gaming problems, but there are just some things I don't understand.

I'm using Lutris along with wine. Not only that, but I'm using it to play Skyrim Special Edition which I downloaded from GOG, but the Character's voice audio is not coming through. All the other audio is fine like the atmosphere, surround sound and the game runs totally fine. I went through and did all the graphics drivers and stuff, took a long time for me to figure out how to get it all to work. But my first benchmark for a new computer is Skyrim, so getting that to work is what I'm focused on for now.

I tried doing some research into this, but I keep seeing stuff about
Xaudio2_7 and WINEDLLOVERRIDES="xaudio2_7=n,b" but I am really just not understanding what the heck is going on lmao. I don't know if I should any alternate solutions for it. Or should I?

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This won't be an Ubuntu problem but wine config. I would have asked this on wineHQ. In the mean time: https://hamy.xyz/labs/lutris-skyrim-sse  seems to answer something similar. So does https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/rnnwvx/no_voice_and_no_music_in_skyrim_le/